# How to translate «predicate of» to Spanish?

Tags: traducción, verbos

I am reading a theology book, and I found this excerpt:

> Bavinck strongly opposes all notions of divine temporality and mutability: “The idea of becoming predicated of the divine being is of no help whatever in theology.” To deny immutability is to “rob God of his divine nature and religion of its firm foundation and assured comfort."

I want to understand it or translate it in Spanish. What I found so hard: «becoming predicated of»

I have this on my own, but it seems no meaning for me:

- La idea de convertirse en afirmado del ser divino ...
- La idea de ser predicado del ser divino ...

Please help me.

Comment: Technically, you are probably looking at the translation of the Dutch sentence "Er is toch in de theologie, met toepassing op het
Goddelijk wezen, niets mede aan te vangen."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure whether the given phrase is necessarily an accurate translation from the original *Gereformeerde Dogmatiek*, but in any case, "predicate of" is philosophical jargon for asserting that a predicate is true of a subject.

Thus, if I had to recast this in plain English, I would say:

> Becoming as a concept, applied to the divine being, is of no help whatsoever in theology.

Or:

> The idea that the divine being is capable of becoming something is of no help whatsoever in theology.

Thus, I would translate the first part of the phrase like this:

> La idea de «convertirse», aplicada al ser divino....